# store new values at every index of an empty matrix by implementing a nested for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have tried storing the new calculated values in the second for loop to qz as qz[velocity][iterations] but it always returns "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index".

```
iterations = 10
Kz_mean = 0.85
Kz_std = 0.12
Kz = np.random.normal(Kz_mean, Kz_std, iterations)
velocities = np.linspace(50, 250, 41)


def velocity_pressure(Kz, velocities, iterations):
    qz = np.empty([velocities, iterations])
    for velocity in range(len(velocities)):
        for iters in range(iterations):
            qz[velocity][iters] = (0.00256 * Kz[iters] * velocities[velocity]**2)
            return qz

rv = velocity_pressure(Kz, velocities, iterations)
print(rv)
```

I expect rv to be velocity*iterations size matrix but get the error "only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is an error in your code when you define `qz`, it should be :

```
qz = np.empty((len(velocities), iterations))
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked! So, silly of me. Forgive me, for I am a python beginner.

Comment: No need to apologize, we've all been there :)